# How to add submenu to menuButton in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Following is the code:

```
<p:menuButton styleClass="menuItems" value="File">
        <p:menuitem styleClass="menuItems" value="View" url=""/>
        <p:menuitem styleClass="menuItems" value="Edit" url=""/>
</p:menubutton>
```

When I add `<p:submenu>` to `<p:menuButton>`, UI is not rendering correctly. Want to add `<p:submenu>` inside `<p:menuButton>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not supported with `p:menuButton`. You might want to try `p:tieredMenu` in combination with the `overlay="true"` attribute:

```html
<p:commandButton id="dynaButton" value="Show" type="button" icon="pi pi-external-link"/>
<p:tieredMenu overlay="true" trigger="dynaButton" my="left top" at="left bottom" style="width:200px">
    <p:submenu label="File" icon="pi pi-fw pi-file">
        <p:submenu label="New" icon="pi pi-fw pi-plus">
            <p:menuitem value="Bookmark" icon="pi pi-fw pi-bookmark"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Video" icon="pi pi-fw pi-video"/>
        </p:submenu>
        <p:menuitem value="Delete" icon="pi pi-fw pi-trash"/>
        <p:divider />
        <p:menuitem value="Export" icon="pi pi-fw pi-external-link"/>
    </p:submenu>
    ...
    <p:menuitem value="Quit" icon="pi pi-fw pi-power-off"/>
</p:tieredMenu>
```

See also:

- https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/tieredMenu.xhtml

Comment: Thank you..able to implement and working..have one minor issue...all the menuitem are not displayed in the screen..the menus displayed on click of a button are not displayed below the button but it is displayed above the commandbutton.

Comment: <p:commandButton styleClass=".MenuButtons" id="adminButton" value="administration']}"/>
    <p:tieredMenu overlay="true" trigger="adminButton" my="left top" at="left bottom">
   <p:menuitem styleClass=".MenuItems" value="file" url=" "/>
   <p:submenu  label=".next']}">
    <p:menuitem styleClass=".MenuItems" value="edit" url=" "/>
    <p:menuitem styleClass=".MenuItems" value="revert" url=""/>
   </p:submenu>
   <p:menuitem styleClass=".MenuItems" value="home" url="" rendered="" />
   <p:menuitem styleClass=".MenuItems" value="quit" url="" rendered="" />
  </p:tieredMenu>

Comment: Please ask a new question for you new problem.